# I want to delete/withdraw messages

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs

I want to delete a sent message. I see check boxes that imply I can select messages and then perform an action, but I see no related buttons.

[image]

**Feature request:** Allow me to delete or withdraw sent messages.

Otherwise, I propose removing the check boxes that have no function in this context.

Comment: You can't delete those same way that we can't delete our Stack Exchange inbox items. Better separate this into two different questions: one is a support question asking what's the purpose of these checkboxes, and one is a feature request asking to let us delete messages. You decide how to split, but it should be split.

Comment: Anyway, until you decide which is the support question, the answer is [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/e0u7o.jpg). :) (so actually this should be a bug report)

Comment: @ShadowWizard My question was really a rhetorical complaint about the UI. I revised the question to focus on the feature request.

Comment: Nicely done, cheers!

Comment: The recipient gets an email notification when you send a message, and they can reply to this notification to reply to you. So deleting a message is not going to be a viable feature request really, as the recipient will already have it and be able to reply to you, even if we removed it from the web-based messaging UI.

Comment: @JonH not at all. This here is clearly asking for a way to delete messages.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - But the buttons are missing that is why you cannot delete.

Comment: @JonH no. There used to be "mark as read" and "mark as unread" option, that's all. There was never an option to delete messages.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Got you boss, i retract!

Comment: @Juice ever since MSE/MSO split, Careers bug/requests posted on MSO used to be migrated to MSE. This is the first time I see the opposite. Why the change of mind? This is highly confusing.

Comment: @AlexWarren I understand. I still want to delete! :)

Answer (score -2):

Regarding the checkboxes, as can be seen in [this old screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0u7o.jpg) (3+ years), there used to be "mark read" and "mark unread" buttons in the UI, which were removed at some point.

So, the checkboxes are most likely an overlook, a bug, that should not be there. However, I support the request to let them stay, and add a "delete" button or at least "archive".